# BST node deletion loop in C++

Tags: c++, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm building a function for deleting a node in a binary tree; since two of three cases are fairly simple (no children and 1 child) I've built another function to "re-arrange" the nodes beneath the one I'm trying to delete, in case it has two children.
I built the function so that it returns a pointer, which is the re-arranged subtree, but I've also tried making a function that just changes the tree itself, without returning a value, but both seem to create a loop where the tree changes: when I try to print the tree, it's stuck printing between the value I replace and it's left child, back and forth until eventually a segfault 11 pops up. I'm really lost as even the debugger isn't helping me understand where the issue is, can anyone tell me where to look? Thank you in advance for your kind attention and your time

Here is the tree I was thinking of before the deletion:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1AYR.png)
And here it is after the deletion:[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pDSB.png)

'''

```
if (found the value)      // value is head (recursive)
{
Node* to_delete = head;
...
head = subNode (head);
delete to_delete;
}
```

'''

```
Node* b_tree :: subNode (Node*&head)
{
    Node*curr = head->right;
    if (((!curr->right) && (!curr->left)) || (!curr->left))      // if it's a leaf or at least if the left pointer is NULL
    {
        curr->left = head->left;
        head->left = NULL;
        Node*to_return = curr;
        return to_return;
    }else               // if there's a lower value...
    {
        while (curr->left != NULL) // find the lowest in the sub-tree
        {
            curr = curr->left;
        }
        if (!curr->right)
        {
            curr->right = head->right;
            curr->left = head->left;
            Node* to_return = curr;
            curr = NULL;
            return to_return;
        } else {
            Node* temp = curr->right;
            curr->right = head->right;
            curr->left = head->left;
            Node*to_return = curr;
            curr = temp;
            return to_return;
        }
    }
};
```

''' Here's the whole code
'''

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Node
{
    Node ();
    Node (string, int);
    string name;
    int value;
    Node* left;
    Node* right;
};

Node :: Node ()
{
    left = right = NULL;
}

Node :: Node (string nome, int valore)
{
    this->name = nome;
    this->value = valore;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
};

class b_tree
{
    private:
        Node* head;
        void insRic (Node*&, Node);
        void stampaRic (Node*);
        void deleteRic (Node*&, Node);
        Node* subNode (Node*&);
    public:
        b_tree ();
        void inserimento (Node);
        void delete (Node);
        void stampa ();
};

b_tree :: b_tree ()
{
    this->head = NULL;
};

void b_tree :: inserimento (Node temp)
{
    insRic(this->head, temp);
};

void b_tree :: insRic (Node*& head, Node temp)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        if (temp.value < head->value)
        {
            insRic(head->left, temp);
        } else if (temp.value > head->value)
            {
                insRic(head->right, temp);
            }
    } else
    {
        head = new Node (temp.name, temp.value);
    }
};

void b_tree :: stampa ()
{
    stampaRic (this->head);
};

void b_tree :: stampaRic (Node* head)
{
    if (head != NULL)
    {
        if (head->left != NULL)
        {
            stampaRic (head->left);
        }
        cout << "Nome: " << head->name << " | Valore: " << head->value << endl;
        if (head->right != NULL)
        {
            stampaRic (head->right);
        }   
    }
};

Node* b_tree :: subNode (Node*&head)
{
    Node*curr = head->right;
    if (((!curr->right) && (!curr->left)) || (!curr->left))      // if it's a leaf or at least if the leftious pointer is NULL
    {
        curr->left = head->left;
        head->left = NULL;
        Node*to_return = curr;
        return to_return;
    }else               // if there's a lower value...
    {
        while (curr->left != NULL) // find the lowest in the sub-tree
        {
            curr = curr->left;
        }
        if (!curr->right)
        {
            curr->right = head->right;
            curr->left = head->left;
            Node* to_return = curr;
            curr = NULL;
            return to_return;
        } else {
            Node* temp = curr->right;
            curr->right = head->right;
            curr->left = head->left;
            Node*to_return = curr;
            curr = temp;
            return to_return;
        }
    }
};

void b_tree :: delete (Node temp)
{
    deleteRic (this->head, temp);
};

void b_tree :: deleteRic (Node*& head, Node temp)
{
    if (head != NULL)                   // if head points ot something
    {
        if (head->value != temp.value)          // if the node I'm trying to delete has a different name, jusr call it again until it finds it
        {
            if (temp.value < head->value)
            {
                eliminaRic (head->left, temp);
            } else if (temp.value > head->value)
                {
                    eliminaRic (head->right, temp);
                }
        } else      // once I've found the value I'm trying to delete;
        {
            Node*to_delete = head;
            if ((head->right == NULL) && (head->left == NULL))  // checking that the node is not a leaf
            {
                head = NULL;
                delete to_delete;
            } else if (head->left == NULL)          // if leftious pointer is null
                {
                    to_delete = head->right;
                    delete to_delete;
                } else if (head->right == NULL)          // if right pointer in null
                    {
                        head = head->left;
                        delete to_delete;
                    }
            else if ((head->right != NULL) && (head->left != NULL))               // if neither pointer is null (2 children);
            {
                head = subNode (head);
                delete to_delete;       
            }
        }
    }
}

int main ()
{
    
    b_tree*albero = new b_tree ();
    Node temp = Node ();
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        cout << "Insert name and value; name: "; cin >> temp.name; cout << " value : "; cin >> temp.value; cout << endl;
        albero->inserimento(temp);
    }
    albero->stampa();
    cout << "Insert the value of the node you wish to delete: "; cin >> temp.value;
    albero->delete(temp);
    albero->stampa();
    
}
```

'''

Comment: Why you need in a binary tree next and prev? This is somethin I would expect in a list but not binary tree.

Comment: Because in a binary tree, as "binary" implies, each node has a maximum of two "children" beneath it; usually all the values on the left  of a node are lesser than the node's value and the values on the right are greater.

Comment: Side note on *"I've built another function to "re-arrange" the nodes beneath the one"*: that's a bad idea, as it will lead to more unbalanced trees than without such a strategy. Secondly, the algorithm involved is more complex than the original deletion algorithm you try to avoid.

Comment: So why not using left and right instead, like it´s done in other implementations?

Comment: next is fully equal to right and left is fully equal to prev, it's not a matter of the pointer's name.

Comment: @Logu Maybe because using `prev` and `next` are confusing when implementing a binary tree?

Comment: @trincot In which ways is it more complex? If I have to take into account every possible option how can I make the function any lighter?

Comment: @Logu It is very dificult to understand you code, when using wired names. At least you should show the whole code.

Comment: Can you draw a picture of the original tree and of the rearranged tree? Indicate which node from the original tree goes where in the rearranged tree.

Comment: We are assuming all (and I mean *all*) of your code concerning creation, insertion, etc. is working.  The problem is -- we can't assume that because we don't have the code.  The place where it crashes now is only where things finally break down -- maybe the cause of the crash started way before any of the code you posted actually is invoked.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought that asking a question about a specific problem that I have already "located" was better than just giving out the whole code. The code concerning creation, insertion and printing is indeed fully working, otherwise I would concentrate on that part of the program. I'll update the post right away with the whole code, thank you

Comment: @Logu Just as an example you could insert some corupted data and there will be no problem as long you not triing to aces it.

Comment: void delete could be a problem since delete is a keyword in C++.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I uploaded an example of the tree I had in mind and, by just changing the values without rearranging the whole tree and deleting the node from which I took the values, somehow the tree still holds the reference to the node I deleted, it only deletes the name but keeps the value and in fact prints it.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some issues:

- The main problem is in the second half of `subNode`. The following line (that occurs twice) creates a cycle:

  ```
  curr->next = head->next;
  ```

  As `curr` is a descendant of `head->next`, this closes a cycle. This cycle is not broken by anything that follows.
- `curr = NULL` or `curr = temp` is useless. It only sets a value of a variable and doesn't mutate the tree (which may be what you thought it did).
- `to_return` should not be set to `curr`, but to `head->next`.
- Not a problem, but the `if` condition at the top of `subNode` is equivalent to just `!curr->prev`.
- Not a problem, but `head->prev = NULL` is not really needed, as `head` is going to be deleted anyway.

When these points are taken into account, some code repetition can be avoided, and the code can be reduced to the following:

```
Node* b_tree :: subNode (Node*&head)
{
    Node* curr = head->next;
    while (curr->prev != NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->prev;
    }
    curr->prev = head->prev;
    return head-next;
};
```

Side note: this algorithm will more quickly increase the gravity with which the tree is unbalanced, as a whole subtree is moved at a lower place in the tree. This may even double the height of the tree with just one delete operation. I would therefor prefer the original, popular algorithm for deletion.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I'll try to just implement the "popular" algorithm for deletion, thank you again!

Comment: But, am I not setting a pointer to point to nothing when I do "curr = NULL"? How do I free a pointer in the tree?

Comment: You can mutate the tree by setting a `prev` or `next` property, not by assigning to a variable. Whatever you assign to `curr` impacts `curr`, nothing else. `curr` may have a reference to a node, but assigning again to `curr` just replaces that reference. It does not mutate the parent of the node that `curr` was referencing before. Just compare it with another assignment you do `curr = curr->left;`. There you did not expect you were mutating the tree, right? It is the same when you do `curr = NULL`.

Comment: Well but if I set a variable, which is indeed a pointer like 'curr', to NULL, doesn't it mean that that pointer will be pointing to nothing, or very simply returning no value? I'm having a hard time understanding what you mean with "mutate the parent node" as I am indeed just trying to replace references in order to re-arrange the elements, making it so that a reference to an element later on in the tree appears before and makes it possible to continue searching through the tree